How do I stop Access database with clipboard monitoring from crashing when I cut text from code modules?
I have an Access database that needs to use clipboard monitoring to enable and disable a button that imports data from the clipboard (based on whether it's appropriate for import or not). It appears to be mostly stable when clipboard monitoring is turned on, with the notable exception that whenever I cut multiple lines of code from the code window, it crashes immediately before any VBA code even executes. Copying from the code window is fine, cutting from anywhere else is fine.
I'm using a modified version of the code from here (partly functionality modifications, partly changing some data types to LongPtr, but the crashes were occurring before the data type changes), in a separate module as directed. I tried adding an error handler, but since it was crashing before even executing the code, it didn't really make any difference. My guess is that cutting text from the code pane somehow makes the address from the AddressOf statement invalid, but if that's the issue I don't know how to get around it.
https://www.mrexcel.com/board/threads/use-excel-as-a-clipboard.1216045/
Modified version:
Option Explicit

Private Declare PtrSafe Function SetWindowLong Lib "user32" Alias "SetWindowLongPtrA" (ByVal hwnd As LongPtr, ByVal nIndex As Long, ByVal dwNewLong As LongPtr) As LongPtr
Private Declare PtrSafe Function CallWindowProc Lib "user32" Alias "CallWindowProcA" (ByVal lpPrevWndFunc As LongPtr, ByVal hwnd As LongPtr, ByVal Msg As Long, ByVal wParam As LongPtr, ByVal lParam As LongPtr) As LongPtr
Private Declare PtrSafe Function CreateWindowEx Lib "user32" Alias "CreateWindowExA" (ByVal dwExStyle As Long, ByVal lpClassName As String, ByVal lpWindowName As String, ByVal dwStyle As Long, ByVal x As Long, ByVal y As Long, ByVal nWidth As Long, ByVal nHeight As Long, ByVal hWndParent As LongPtr, ByVal hMenu As LongPtr, ByVal hInstance As LongPtr, lpParam As Any) As LongPtr
Private Declare PtrSafe Function DestroyWindow Lib "user32" (ByVal hwnd As LongPtr) As Long
Private Declare PtrSafe Function OpenClipboard Lib "user32" (ByVal hwnd As LongPtr) As Long
Private Declare PtrSafe Function CloseClipboard Lib "user32" () As Long
Private Declare PtrSafe Function IsClipboardFormatAvailable Lib "user32" (ByVal wFormat As Long) As Long
Private Declare PtrSafe Function GetClipboardSequenceNumber Lib "user32" () As Long
Private Declare PtrSafe Function GetClipboardData Lib "user32" (ByVal wFormat As Long) As LongPtr
Private Declare PtrSafe Function AddClipboardFormatListener Lib "user32" (ByVal hwnd As LongPtr) As Long
Private Declare PtrSafe Function RemoveClipboardFormatListener Lib "user32" (ByVal hwnd As LongPtr) As Long
Private Declare PtrSafe Function GlobalLock Lib "kernel32" (ByVal hMem As LongPtr) As LongPtr
Private Declare PtrSafe Function GlobalUnlock Lib "kernel32" (ByVal hMem As LongPtr) As Long
Private Declare PtrSafe Function lstrlenW Lib "kernel32.dll" (ByVal lpString As LongPtr) As Long
Private Declare PtrSafe Function lstrcpyW Lib "kernel32.dll" (ByVal lpString1 As LongPtr, ByVal lpString2 As LongPtr) As Long
Private Declare PtrSafe Function SetProp Lib "user32" Alias "SetPropA" (ByVal hwnd As LongPtr, ByVal lpString As String, ByVal hData As LongPtr) As Long
Private Declare PtrSafe Function GetProp Lib "user32" Alias "GetPropA" (ByVal hwnd As LongPtr, ByVal lpString As String) As LongPtr
Private Declare PtrSafe Function RemoveProp Lib "user32" Alias "RemovePropA" (ByVal hwnd As LongPtr, ByVal lpString As String) As LongPtr


Sub Start()
    Call CreateClipWindow
End Sub

Sub Finish()
    Call CleanUp
End Sub


'_______________________________________ PRIVATE ROUTINES __________________________________________________

Private Sub CreateClipWindow()
    Dim lHiddenWnd As LongPtr
    
    If GetProp(Application.hwndAccessApp, "HiddenWnd") = 0 Then
        lHiddenWnd = CreateWindowEx(0, "Static", vbNullString, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)
        Call SetProp(Application.hwndAccessApp, "HiddenWnd", lHiddenWnd)
        Call AddClipboardFormatListener(lHiddenWnd)
        Call SubClassClipBoardWatcherWindow(lHiddenWnd)
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub CleanUp()
    Call RemoveClipboardFormatListener(GetProp(Application.hwndAccessApp, "HiddenWnd"))
    Call SubClassClipBoardWatcherWindow(GetProp(Application.hwndAccessApp, "HiddenWnd"), False)
    Call DestroyWindow(GetProp(Application.hwndAccessApp, "HiddenWnd"))
    Call RemoveProp(Application.hwndAccessApp, "HiddenWnd")
End Sub
  
Private Sub SubClassClipBoardWatcherWindow(ByVal hwnd As LongPtr, Optional ByVal bSubclass As Boolean = True)

    Const GWLP_WNDPROC = (-4)
    If bSubclass Then
        If GetProp(Application.hwnd, "PrevProcAddr") = 0 Then
            Call SetProp(Application.hwndAccessApp, "PrevProcAddr", _
                SetWindowLong(hwnd, GWLP_WNDPROC, AddressOf ClipBoardWindowCallback))
        End If
    Else
        If GetProp(Application.hwndAccessApp, "PrevProcAddr") Then
            Call SetWindowLong(hwnd, GWLP_WNDPROC, GetProp(Application.hwndAccessApp, "PrevProcAddr"))
            Call RemoveProp(Application.hwndAccessApp, "PrevProcAddr")
        End If
    End If
End Sub

Private Function ClipBoardWindowCallback( _
        ByVal hwnd As LongPtr, _
        ByVal uMsg As Long, _
        ByVal wParam As LongPtr, _
        ByVal lParam As LongPtr _
    ) As LongPtr


    Const WM_CLIPBOARDUPDATE = &H31D
    Static lPrevSerial As Long
  
    Call SubClassClipBoardWatcherWindow(hwnd, False)
    If uMsg = WM_CLIPBOARDUPDATE Then
        If lPrevSerial <> GetClipboardSequenceNumber Then
            
           'DO STUFF HERE

            lPrevSerial = GetClipboardSequenceNumber
        End If
    End If
    Call SubClassClipBoardWatcherWindow(hwnd, True)
    ClipBoardWindowCallback = CallWindowProc(GetProp(Application.hwndAccessApp, "PrevProcAddr"), hwnd, uMsg, wParam, lParam)
End Function

Private Sub Auto_Close()
    Call CleanUp
End Sub


During development, you hold down the shift key to allow the application to startup without having run any VBA code, nor have launched any forms. This allows you to develop and write code. I would think and suggest then such clipboard code not going to matter during development. When you done developing, then you can exit, and then re-start the application - thus allowing your startup code and things like the clipboard code to run. However, during development cycle, no such code should be run or have run.

90% of the time I remember to close the main form, which also closes the clipboard monitor, before I do any coding. But I would like the database to not crash the other 10% of the time.

What about the line GetProp(Application.hwnd, "PrevProcAddr") = 0  in SubClassClipBoardWatcherWindow?

And what about the declaration of SetWindowLong? Is that one always correct?  The Win64 conditional compiler constant is used to determine which version (32-bit or 64-bit) of Office is running!

What about them? I had a version of the code where I wrapped that in an nz, and a version where it was looking for NULL_PTR, and it didn't make any difference. I'm not using the conditional compiler because everyone is on Win64 (and Office 64).

So, everyone is using Office 64-bit. Why do you use longptr then? And what about my question referring to GetProp(Application.hwnd, "PrevProcAddr") = 0.

Yes, everyone is on Office 64-bit. In any case, right now I am the only user, and I'm on Office 64-bit. I would think that if either of those two things were the issue it would be crashing all the time and not on that one very specific scenario.

So, you are saying GetProp(Application.hwnd, "PrevProcAddr") = 0.compiles, right?

Look at it this way: The crash is occurring outside of my code; i.e., after the cut event and before Access starts processing the ClipBoardWindowCallback code. So essentially it looks as though SubClassClipBoardWatcherWindow is creating a clipboard watcher that specifically can't handle text being cut from the code window. Which to my mind points to an AddressOf problem, but I don't know API stuff nearly well enough to be sure of that, much less what to do about it.

But your posted code does not even compile.

Ah, sorry, I missed your point of emphasis. I was manually modifying the original code to match my code because I don't log in to non-work sites at work, and I missed that one. It's Application.hwndAccessApp in my actual code.

Then the question arises: What else did you miss? Calling API functions is very sensitive, especially when it comes to data types, particularly if incorrect ones are passed.

Fair enough. I just copied the code out of StackOverflow and checked it at work, and the hwnd property in that GetProp line is the only thing I missed.

Basically, what Albert wrote. It is a horrible idea to have this code running while editing the VBA code, and especially cutting text from there. Once you have experienced enough crashes, I'm sure you'll always remember to stop the code before editing.  ;-)

So is the answer that this is just what happens and there's no way to prevent it? It's not the answer I was hoping for, but it is definitely an answer.

No startup code or even any form with a timer running can be reliably used during the development cycle.  During a development day, I will exit and re-start Access 100's of times, since my startup code interferes with the development of code. So, shift-key by-pass to start working on code. Once done, you exit (and the accDB file will still be highlighted), and then you tap enter key to launch again in "user test mode".  Boatloads of startup code to hide nav pane and f10 key settings will  etc. be changed with typical startup code ALL of which prevents the developer working on such code.

Yep, I have my own methodology for this - 99% of the time closing the main form turns off everything I need to turn off, and 90-95% of the time I remember to close it.
If the crashes are just an inevitable result of cutting from the code window when clipboard monitoring is active (from a different module; I'm not completely insane) and not a result of a deficiency in my code, then I'll just live with it and work around it.
